# Odd behavior of setoid_rewrite in Coq

Tags: url-rewriting, typeclass, coq

I am having problems with rewriting using the `setoid_rewrite` tactic. In the following instance declaration, I expect that `setoid_rewrite fmapComp` would rewrite `fmap iso ∘ fmap inv` to `fmap (iso ∘ inv)`. However, Coq reports that "no progress was made" during rewriting:

```
Instance functorsPreserveIsomorphisms
 `{C : Cat o η} `{D : Cat u ρ}
   {a b : o} {φ : o → u} (F : Functor C D φ) (I : a ≅ b) : φ a ≅ φ b.
Proof.
  apply (Build_Isomorphism _ _ _ (φ a) (φ b) (fmap iso) (fmap inv)).

 o : Type
 η : o → o → Type
 C : Cat o η
 u : Type
 ρ : u → u → Type
 D : Cat u ρ
 a : o
 b : o
 φ : o → u
 F : Functor C D φ
 I : a ≅ b
 ============================
  fmap iso ∘ fmap inv ≡ id (φ a)
```

I don't understand why `setoid_rewrite` fails. For reference, the *same* command works in other contexts using the *same* terms. For example, it rewrites either side of the following goal to the other:

```
Lemma worksotherwise
 `{C : Cat o η} `{D : Cat u ρ}
   {a b : o} {φ : o → u} (F : Functor C D φ) (I : a ≅ b) :
     fmap iso ∘ fmap inv ≡ fmap (iso ∘ inv)

 o : Type
 η : o → o → Type
 C : Cat o η
 u : Type
 ρ : u → u → Type
 D : Cat u ρ
 a : o
 b : o
 φ : o → u
 F : Functor C D φ
 I : a ≅ b
 ============================
  fmap iso ∘ fmap inv ≡ fmap (iso ∘ inv)
```

It's unclear why `setoid_rewrite` works in the second case but not the first. For reference, `≡` is `equiv` and `fmap` is `Proper`. Other than that `≅`, `Functor` and `Cat` are classes, I don't see any other relevant facts. Also, `setoid_replace` works fine.

Comment: Shot in the dark: something fishy going on in implicit arguments, such as terms that are convertible when some tactic requires them to be equal? Try comparing the two situations under `No Implicit Arguments`.

Comment: Looking through the terms and context with `Set Printing All` doesn't reveal anything. What's odd is - using `setoid_rewrite` and *then* rewriting using the desired equality works fine - but the terms composing the expressions don't appear to have changed.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem occurred. Starting off fresh and controlling implicit arguments more strongly with only the needed definitions for the instance resolved the problem. So I assume something happened buried in an imported module, somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark without seeing the whole development, but sometimes, when you can't see a difference, it means that there's a difference in a part you don't see. Namely, implicit arguments.

For example, you might have an implicit argument somewhere that appears identically in two locations in the working proof attempt, and that appears in two distinct but interconvertible (or even merely equal) in the non-working proof attempt. Occasionally tactics require identical terms to fire up, whereas interconvertible terms would suffice with the same proof tree, and equal terms would suffice with judicious introduction of `eq_refl`. When you're working with high-level tactics such as the setoid tactics, it can be difficult to understand what's going on under the hood.

Try comparing the situations under `Set Printing Implicit` or `Set Printing All`, or working with `No Strict Implicit` or `No Implicit Arguments` for a small part of the proof.